# Why does my Outlined Diffuse 3 shader seem "detached" at a distance?

Tags: unity, shaders, graphics, graphic-effects

I'm using the *Outlined Diffuse 3* shader from Unity and I'm having a problem with it: the outline looks great when the camera is near the object, but at a distance, it looks detached.

From nearby (looks good):

[image: OK]

From afar (looks bad; see the shelf and books):

[image: not OK]

How can I fix this graphical anomaly?

Answer (score 2):

I guess you refers to [this shader](http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php?title=Outlined_Diffuse_3). That's not an "anomaly", it's how this shader is supposed to work(not a great result imho).

So let's have a quick look to the relevant code:

```
float3 norm   = mul ((float3x3)UNITY_MATRIX_IT_MV, v.normal);
```

This first line transforms the normal from object space to view space.

```
float2 offset = TransformViewToProjection(norm.xy);
```

The second line projects the xy normal components from view space. Basically you'll end up with a vector describing "how much" the normal point to right and up direction relatively to the screen.

```
o.pos.xy += offset * o.pos.z * _Outline;
```

This is the "guilty line" :) . The projected vertex position is **offset** by the projected normal calculated before by an amount proportional to `_Outline`(the size of the outline you specify by inspector) and the distance from the camera (`o.pos.z`).

The idea behind is that if you don't multiply by the distance, the outline will become thinner depending on how fare you are from the camera. So basically it should guarantee that the outline should stay on the same (clip space) distance independently from camera distance. (Just comment the multiplication by o.pos.z and you will see).

So basically in the second picture what seems a larger outline, is an outline of the same width when projected (de facto larger if you consider the width relative to the world size of the object).

Note that the "outline" is simply the same model draw with front face culling:

```
Name "OUTLINE"
Cull Front
```

---

Side note

There are several way of drawing outlines. The way you are using produce several problems other than the outline width, for example:

- crack on hard edges (see the space in the bottom left corner of the shelf)
- missing outlines (see the outline is not visible on the right side of the book)

There are several better techniques, both for the vertex shader or as post process effect (es. sobel filter for edge detection). 
Which technique you can use is highly dependent on the final look desired, and maybe depends on your asset characteristic too.

Comment: Could one improve the existing shader by normalizing offset first? In the offending screenshot, the front of the book is almost facing the camera, so its projected normal is close to zero, and the outline on the front side ends up too thin. By normalizing, we apply the same outline thickness (at a particular depth) all around the object - though it will still act up for faces that point directly at the camera.

Comment: @DMGregory: I guess you are right. Honestly I've always used different approaches to outlining, btw I guess normalizing would force the width to stay constant.